# accessing shipping rates in order complete hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The client has very specific shipping requirements so I built a shipping plugin that works perfectly. But I need to pull the chosen shipping info in a specific format to send a purchase order to a 3rd party provider.

In the shipping plugin I store these values as follows:

```
$rate1cfree = array(
   'id' => 'shipping_method_courier_free',
   'label' => 'Courier (free)',
   'cost' => '0',
   'calc_tax' => 'per_item',
   'meta_data' => array(
      'delivery_channel' => 'NAT',
      'delivery_service' => 'EXP'
    )
);
$this->add_rate( $rate1cfree );
```

The 2 meta values that I need in the order complete hook is 'delivery_channel' and 'delivery_service'.

Now in my woocommerce_payment_complete function I can pull most of the order data using:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order_data = $order->get_data();
```

The problem is that the meta values comes through as follows:

```
    [shipping_lines] => Array
    (
        [358] => WC_Order_Item_Shipping Object
            (

                [meta_data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                            (
                                [current_data:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2515
                                        [key] => delivery_channel
                                        [value] => NAT
                                    )

                                [data:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2515
                                        [key] => delivery_channel
                                        [value] => NAT
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                            (
                                [current_data:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2516
                                        [key] => delivery_service
                                        [value] => EXP
                                    )

                                [data:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2516
                                        [key] => delivery_service
                                        [value] => EXP
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

And no matter which ever methods I try and use I can't seem to access those values. I've tries using get_post_meta(), get_meta_data(), get_meta() and pretty much anything that looks like it could help on this page: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm completely stuck. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, my co-working hero solved it as follows:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

foreach( $order->get_items( 'shipping' ) as $item_id => $shipping_item_obj ){
    $shipping_item_data = $shipping_item_obj->get_data();
    $ship_info = $shipping_item_data['meta_data'];
    foreach($ship_info as $ship_key => $ship_value){
        $ship[$ship_key] = $ship_value->get_data();
    }
}

print_r($ship);
```